# How to prevent my mouse from automatically clicking, grabbing and selecting text in Parrot OS

Tags: linux, debian, mouse, vmware, parrot-os

I'm running Parrot OS. Whenever I'm using the keyboard or mouse, random clicks or selection of text happens. I accidentally end up deleting the text I was typing or ends up doing some other unintentional function. The cursor randomly respawns on another part of the screen.

This happens regardless of whether I'm using the trackpad or the mouse.
The issue repeats on the vms I run using Vmware.

My hardware specifications are the following

- Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz × 8
- Memory: 15.3 GB
- Graphics: Intel Xe
- OS: Parrot OS 5.3

I tried tweaking the following to no avail

- VM hardware settings
- DPI settings on host and VM
- Mouse sensitivity and acceleration on host and VM
- Checked mouse and trackpad for hardware issues using xinput
- Testing host without VMWARE running

I previously had Linux mint and I didn't have issues with it

**Edit**: I disabled Dell trackpad using an xinput command.
xinput set-prop "DLL0945:00 06CB:CDE6 Touchpad" "Device Enabled" 0

This fixed the issue. But It's not a reliable solution as I need the trackpad.

Comment: Unplug the mouse & see if it stops. If it does, try another mouse.

Comment: I tried that before. It didn't work.
However I tried something else now and it worked. See original post for update

Comment: Trackpad is damaged then, or the battery is swollen, pressing up against it from behind..

Comment: How does it only happen when I use the mouse or trackpad then? Shouldn't it happen always in that case?

Comment: I don't know - it's up to you to investigate further. You've got your 'starter for ten'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Some trackpads may behave like that in same distros but are otherwise fine in Windows or distros that somehow support them correctly.

Comment: Does VMWare have an option to not pass through the trackpad data? What VMware product are you using?